# Changing toggle button's color for pre lollipop versions

Tags: android, colors, background, togglebutton

I have a problem with my toggle button.
It seems that the attribute line of `<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primaryColor</item>` is not working on pre21 versions on toggle buttons, but does on ordinary buttons. On 21+ versions it works on both.

I tried to follow some tutorials on changing it's background color :

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_toggle_button"
```

which is:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/primaryColor"
        />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/primaryColor" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/primaryColor" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/primaryColor" />
</selector>
```

but this is the result :  [image]

it's big and it lost it's underline.

I just want to change this button color from gray to blue, hoping for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Using support library's `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` should do the trick.

add the following to your build.gradle file before using SwitchCompat

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```